# TFS 2013 Build force MSBuild to use Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, msbuild, c#-6.0

I'm having a TFS 2013 build error with the new VS 2015 string interpolation syntax (Unexpected character '$'). I have modified the "Run MSBuild for Project" task of the build process template like so, but it's still not helping.

- CommandLineArguments: String.Format("/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true {0} /tv:14", MSBuildArguments)
- ToolPath: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin"
- ToolVersion: "14.0".

In the build definition, I also specified the "MSBuild Arguments" = /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0.

[image: Run MSBuild task properties]

[image: Build Definition]

Comment: You are compiling C# 6.0 code and it's failing on [String Interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/24/c-sharp-6-0-features/49/string-interpolation#t=201702091617220341898), correct? Also, have you made sure that the build machine has VS 2015 and the version of msbuild you defined? Just making sure.

Comment: Yes and yes. The build machine has VS 2015 and I can build manually on the build machine successfully. I ended up upgrading to the TfvcTemplate.12.xaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, I gave up trying to figure this out and changed the build process template to TfvcTemplate.12.xaml and add this as the MSBuild arguments: /tv:14.0 /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 (in the build definition).

I know this won't help if someone can't upgrade to TfvcTemplate.12.xaml though.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.

Comment: Sure! Looks like there's a waiting period before I can accept my own answer. I'll accept it as soon as it allows me.